# Typescript generic model definition struggle

Tags: typescript

On our Angular project, we use Typescript (2.2.2). I struggle with generics but I think the solution must be simple.

We have a simple service making a http call:

```
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
  return this._service.http.get('/api/users').map(...)
}
getItems():  Observable<any> {
  return this._service.http.get('/api/items').map(...)
}
```

Both requests return an object with this format (example):

**User:**

```
{
  count: 1,
  skip: 0,
  take: 10,
  objects: [
    { name: 'Jo', age: 24 },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 42 }
  ]
}
```

**Item:**

```
{
  count: 1,
  skip: 0,
  take: 10,
  objects: [
    { id: '54qds44', description: 'a great description' },
    { id: '987azex', description 'another description' }
  ]
}
```

I want to replace `any` type with the kind of actual exact model we have returned.

Since I have common parts in ALL my responses, I imagined doing this:

```
// I could be able to use this app wide
class GenericAPIResponseList<T> = {
  count: number;
  skip: number;
  take: number;
  objects: <T[]>
};

// And special models in this particular service
class User = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

class Item = {
  id: string;
  description: string;
}
```

Then in my service:

```
getUsers(): Observable<GenericAPIResponseList<User>>
getItems(): Observable<GenericAPIResponseList<Item>>
```

But it seems this kind of syntax is incorrect for this "generic model containing a generic model".

How can I write this "generic model accepting a list of another model", then place it in my `Observable<>` return definition?

I read about Interfaces or Extends but I'm kind of lost.

Comment: I think you just need to fix your sintax. Remove the `=` on your classes. Change `class GenericAPIResponseList<T> = {` to `class GenericAPIResponseList<T> {` and change this: ` objects: <T[]>` to this ` objects: T[]`. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Is my "generic-ception" valid syntax? `Observable<GenericAPIResponseList<Users>>`

Comment: Yes, it is a valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you got the point, but you have some minor syntax issues :)
Try the following:

```
// I could be able to use this app wide

class GenericAPIResponseList<T> {
  count: number;
  skip: number;
  take: number;
  objects: T[];
}

// And special models in this particular service
class User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

class Item {
  id: string;
  description: string;
}

function getUsers(): Observable<GenericAPIResponseList<User>> {
    return this._service.http.get('/api/users').map(...);
}

function getItems(): Observable<GenericAPIResponseList<Item>> {
  return this._service.http.get('/api/items').map(...);
}
```